# Javascript RegEx - I want to match a pattern other than the first occurance

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to convert this:

`.className#lets.par.ty`

To this:

`.className[id="lets"][class="par"][class="ty"]`

I don't want to alter the first instance of the "."

Here is what I came up with but I know it is absolutely NOT ideal:

```
cssOutput[i] = cssOutput[i]
.replace (/^#/,'?') // convert all start ids to ?    
.replace (/#([^\.#]+)/g,'[id="$1"]') // insert [id=""]
.replace (/\?/g,'#') // convert all start ? back to ids
.replace (/^\./,'?') // convert all start classes to ?   
.replace (/\.([^\.#]+)/g,'[class="$1"]') // insert [class=""]
.replace (/\?/g,'.') // convert all start ? back to classes
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var s = ".className#lets.par.ty";
s = s.replace(/\.(\w+)#(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)/, '.$1[id="$2"][class="$3"][class="$4"]');
```

A demo: http://ideone.com/51XkY

**EDIT**

To skip the first first character of the input, simply do something like this:

```
var tests = ['.className1', '#className2', '.className.class1#class2#class3'];

for(var index in tests) {

  var t = tests[index];

  t = t.charAt(0) + t.substring(1).
      replace(/\.(\w+)/g, '[class="$1"]').
      replace(/#(\w+)/g,  '[id="$1"]');

  print(t);
}
```

which produces:

```
.className1
#className2
.className[class="class1"][id="class2"][id="class3"]
```

Test it online here: http://ideone.com/YmJGu

Comment: Thank you so much Bart!  I feel bad, I should have been more specific.  I am actually passing an array into this replace method and the array may contain any number of different sequences.  For example: [[.className1], [#className2], [.className.class1#class2]] - so it needs to be really flexible.  I might need to do a few passes but I am wondering if in RegEx there is a way to grab a pattern that does not start on the first character.

Answer (score 1):

You can invert the anchor's meaning by enclosing it in a negative lookahead:

```
s = s.replace(/(?!^)\.(\w+)/g, '[class="$1"]')
     .replace(/(?!^)#(\w+)/g,  '[id="$1"]');
```

[**See it in action on ideone.**](http://ideone.com/85hNJ)